# How to add text in between words in edittext when a button is pressed

Tags: android, button, android-studio, android-edittext

I cannot figure out how to add a space between every word the user types into an edittext as I am still a beginner. I have typed the obvious code below.

```
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText2.setText(???);
        }
    });
```

In case it isn't obvious, there are seperate EditTexts. The user types into `edittext` and I am trying to get the text to "come out" in `edittext2` with the spaces added.

**Edit:** Here is the finished code if anyone wants it. I also added a bit that says how many spaces it's added.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                TextView editText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String str = editText.getText().toString();
                str = str.replace(" ", "  ");
                editText2.setText(str);

                String stre = editText2.getText().toString();
                String string = editText.getText().toString();
                int length = string.length();
                int lengthy = stre.length();

                int finale = lengthy - length;

                TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textresult);
                result.setText( finale + " spaces have been added.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work ? Sorry can't test, on my phone.

```
editText2.setText(edit text.getText().toString().replace all(" ", "  "));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
String word = editText.getText().toString();
String sentenceOrSomething = editText2.getText().toString();
String space = " ";

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(sentenceOrSomething)) {
    editText2.setText(word);
} else {
    editText2.setText(sentenceOrSomething + space + word);
}
```

Comment: string is capitalized in Android, check the corrected answer. isEmpty should be perfectly valid, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: A lot of stuff is missing before it will compile, I am not trying to write your Activity. In any event, if it does not work as intended, i might be misunderstanding what outcome you want. The outcome of the code above is whatever was stored in editText2, will be stored again followed by a space, followed by whatever was in editText.